# WSO2 API Manager 1.9.1 - Routing

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there any way in WSO2 API Manger, to read a parameter value from the request xml/json (payload) and based on that value, route the request to different backend endpoints?

Comment: Have you tried mediator extentions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using mediator extensions.

The API Manager has a default mediation flow for the API invocation requests that it receives. You can extend this default mediation flow to route the request.

1. First write a sequence file to change the flow. Sample sequence as
   follows.

> ```
> <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="YahooWeather2">
>   <property name="YQL" 
>         type="Expression" 
>         expression="concat('?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22',syn:get-property('uri.var.zipcode'),',',syn:get-property('uri.var.country'),'%22)format=json')"/>
>   <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" type="Expression" expression="get-property('YQL')" scope="Axis2"/>
> </sequence>
> ```

2. To upload the sequence file to APIM, login as **admin** go to **main->
   Resources-> Browse**
3. Go to  **/_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences/in.** from the
   tree view
4. Click on **Add Resource** upload the sequence file you created.
5. Login to API Publisher ,select the api and click on **edit** and go
   to **Manage** tab.
6. Click on check box for **Check to select a custom sequence to be
   executed in the message flow** and in the **In Flow** dropdown
   select your sequence(*in sample case* **YahooWeather2**) and do
   **Save &    Publish** .
7. Login to API store and subscribe the api and generate an access
   token.

You can check availability from **API Console** in API store. for ferther details refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Change+the+Default+Mediation+Flow+of+API+Requests